# Can I safely remove feature from my model

Tags: regression, logistic, classification

Lets say I have a simple logistic regression model that is built based on 5 features: $A,B,C,D,E$. I measured its performance via Cross Validation and learned that the F-score is 0.7. I then removed features $B$ and $D$ and noticed that the F-score improved to 0.75. Is my intuition right that the model is now better targeting my data and I can safely remove and essentially forget about those features in future fine tuning my model?

Answer (score 0):

F score is computed for the first feature, and another score is computed for the second feature. But it does not indicate anything on the combination of both features , this is the weakness of F score.
SVM, Random Forests, lasso or many algorithms can be considered based on type of data and model being used.
What can help there is sub sampling the data and running the selection algorithms on the subsets. If the results are consistent across the subsets, it is relatively safe to trust the stability of the method on this particular data and therefor straightforward to interpret the data in terms of the ranking.
Find some insights [here](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that F-score is used to evaluate performance of the entire model, not just one feature. It's not that important though for my question. Im mainly interested in knowing if I can simply remove the feature from model if I notice that it makes the model less accurate.